# What is the correct use of the words "will" and "going to"?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between these two sentences: when will we eat? When are we going to eat?

Comment: There re various different circumstances in which one or the other would usually be chosen. I'll just mention the anxious-to-exasperated-tone variants: 'When will we eat?' communicates an anxious concern in a certain tone of voice; 'When are we going to eat?' can add exasperation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying something is going to happen in the future based on present evidence, facts or will, then you use 'going to': `the sky is gray, it is going to rain`.

If you want to talk about the future in a predicting manner, or you made a decision, you can use 'will': `you'll like her`, or `I will not buy this record, it is scratched`. But if you've already made a decision and you want to refer to it, then you use 'going to': `I think I'll have dinner with her. Yes, brother, I'm going out tonight`.

Answering your original question and based on what I just wrote, you'd use `when will we eat?` to appeal for a decision to be made, and you'd ask `when are we going to eat?` suggesting that the decision of "when to eat" is already made and you just want to be informed of its outcome.

Answer (score 0):

In everyday use, I dare to say native speakers would choose ***will*** to talk about spontaneous decisions, or predictions when no evidence is available. It is also used to make promises.

***Going to***, on the other hand, may better be used when talking about plans you've already made or when making predictions based on evidence (E.g. You have a look at the sky and notice the gray clouds and then say *"it's going to rain"*).

Of course, language is a matter of use most times, and different users may have different perceptions on the "correct" use of certain structures.

Now, I almost forget to refer to your question. Both options might be correct in a given context, but if making plans is what you have in mind, I would say "going to" is the best option. If you ask sb "*When are we going to eat?*", you are supposed to agree upon a date, place, etc, and that's what planning is about. Hope it helps!